# Java - Recursively schedule a timer task

Tags: java

Is there a way to run a timer task only after the method completes. The method could take 10 seconds but the timer is set to run every 5 seconds.  I want it to run again only after the 10 seconds are up.

```
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            longRunningMethod();
            timer.schedule(task, 0, 5000);
        }
    };
    timer.schedule(task, 0, 10000);
```

Comment: The bottom most `schedule` invocation starts a new task every 10 seconds. Every task additionally schedules a new task every 5 seconds. This is grains of rice on a chessboard. Very quickly, you are going to have more tasks than there are atoms in the universe (or more likely, an OutOfMemoryError :) )

Comment: You should not be using [the signature which specifies a period](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html#schedule(java.util.TimerTask,%20long,%20long))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`ScheduledExecutorService`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html) which has a [`scheduleWithFixedDelay()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html#scheduleWithFixedDelay(java.lang.Runnable,%20long,%20long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit)) method which does exactly that.

"Creates and executes a periodic action that becomes enabled first after the given initial delay, and subsequently with the given delay between the termination of one execution and the commencement of the next."

So you could do

```
ExecutorService.newScheduledExecutor()
    .submit(this::longRunningMethod, 0, 1000, ChronoUnit.MILLIS);
```

Answer (score 0):

Removing the `timer.schedule(task, 0, 5000);` call will give you behavior you desire.

Your call of `timer.schedule(task, 0, 10000);` schedules repeating tasks every ten seconds.

Answer (score 0):

You need to schedule one-shot timer tasks and create new TimerTask instance every time.

```
class MyTimerTask extends TimerTask {
    private final Timer timer;
    private final long nextScheduleDelay;

    MyTimerTask(Timer timer, long nextScheduleDelay) {
        this.timer = timer;
        this.nextScheduleDelay = nextScheduleDelay;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        longRunningMethod();
        timer.schedule(new MyTimerTask(timer, nextScheduleDelay), nextScheduleDelay);
    }
}

Timer timer = new Timer();
timer.schedule(new MyTimerTask(timer, 1000), 0);
```